# Is it possible to create a twisted bar magnet and will it have a twisted magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I am wondering if a twisted piece of soft iron can be magnetized, and if so, will it have a twisted magnetic field?

I created a 3D CAD drawing to illustrate what this twisted bar magnet would look like and it is shown below in two different views. The first is a perspective 3D view and the second is a top-down view.

[image]

[image]

Although I am mostly interested in finding out if a permanent magnet of this shape can be created, I am also curious to know if an electromagnet with this same shape can be created and if it would also have a twisted magnetic field.

Is it possible to create a twisted bar magnet and will it have a twisted magnetic field?

**EDIT**

I think one way to magnetize a twisted piece of soft iron would be to use two permanent bar magnets. The North end of one permanent magnet would touch one end of the twisted piece of soft iron and the South end of the other permanent magnet would touch the opposite end of the twisted piece of soft iron. I created another 3D CAD drawing to illustrate what this would look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ferromagnetism is explained on a microscopic scale; Within the body of the magnet, the direction of the [field lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_line) is explained by the orientation of [*magnetic domains*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism#Magnetic_domains), and there is no theoretical reason why those could not be oriented to form a "twisted" path. But, *outside* of the body of the magnet, the direction of the field lines will be determined by the magnetic properties of whatever surrounds the magnet (air, vacuum, etc.,) and they will not "remember" the "twist."